# Rename python function def in runtime for cloud function GCP

Tags: python, function, google-cloud-functions, runtime, rename

in GCP nodejs cloud function I use dotenv to rename function called by trigger in runtime in simple mode:
I read the name of deploy function by dotenv-yaml reading from a env_TEST.yml configuration file
Depending of ENVIRONMENT variable in yaml file I will have

- PROD cloud function trigger called prod_fixNameFunction
- UAT cloud function trigger called uat_fixNameFunction
- TEST cloud function trigger called test_fixNameFunction

because I have 3 .env_PROD.yml .env_UAT.yml and .env_TEST.yml file with ENVIRONMENT variable set PROD, UAT and TEST in ENVIRONMENT variable loaded by dotenv.

Example of code to use:

```
require('dotenv-yaml')**.config({ path: '.env_TEST.yml' })**;
const prefix = process.env.ENVIRONMENT === "PROD"
               ? "prod_"
               : (process.env.ENVIRONMENT === "UAT"
                  ? "uat_"
                  : "test_"
                 );

exports[`${prefix}fixNameFunction`] = async (req, res) => {
...
...
}
```

the part of .config({ path: '.env_TEST.yml' }) is used only in local to develop in local cloud function with google library functions-framework for nodejs and other languages.

This is very usefull to deploy cloud function with different name in cloud function and trigger with correct name prod_functionName and uat_functionName and test_functionName in this case you will have 3 function that works for TEST, UAT and PROD environment with all environment parameters loaded correctly.

By **gitLab CI/CD gitlab-ci.yml** I pass correct env file to use (env_TEST.yml, env_UAT.yml, env_PROD.yml) depending of tag name that start **pipeline**.

I saw that exists **dotenv-python** to load environment variables but I can't find an example in runtime to **rename def function of python** with parameter read by dotenv-python library or other library.

**Somebody have a solution that works fine in python to load new name of function by environmnent variable and rename def functionname to [prefix]functionName as previous example in nodejs with environment variable load in prefix ?**

Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a dynamic function name. Here's how you'd do it in Python:

```py
def my_function(request):
    return "Success"

function_name = "whatever"  # Get this from your env file

locals()[function_name] = my_function
```

Then the `whatever()` function would be available to call.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I already solved it yesterday ...
A cleaner solution in the case of Google Cloud Function is to specify the -entry-point parameter with the name of the function in the code to call when the cloud function is activated.
Thanks again and have a nice day.